# Finding modified files in a GitHub PR (ambigious argument with git command)

Tags: github, github-actions

I have the following Rubocop linter in my GitHub Actions workflow, which triggers on a `pull` request to the `dev` branch:

```
      - name: Rubocop Linter
        env:
          DEFAULT_BRANCH: dev
        run: |
          git -C ${GITHUB_WORKSPACE} diff --name-only ${DEFAULT_BRANCH}...${GITHUB_SHA} --diff-filter=d | xargs bin/bundle exec rubocop -c .github/linters/.rubocop.yml
```

Whenever this runs, the following error shows up in the workflow logs:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'dev...3f03b85fd365b84b0a908d3ea5217abd1a08a275': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

Not quite sure why. I was looking at the Super-Linter github repository and saw the following that they were using:

```
./lib/functions/buildFileList.sh:      DIFF_CMD="git -C ${GITHUB_WORKSPACE} diff --name-only ${DEFAULT_BRANCH}...${GITHUB_SHA} --diff-filter=d | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo \"${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/%\"' 2>&1"
```

This seems to do exactly what I'm looking to accomplish, but for some reason the command isn't working for me. I'm essentially trying to run `rubocop` on all changed files in a PR.

If I run this on the command line, I get the following error:

```
$ git -C ${GITHUB_WORKSPACE} diff --name-only ${DEFAULT_BRANCH}...3f03b85fd365b84b0a908d3ea5217abd1a08a275 --diff-filter=d
fatal: ambiguous argument 'dev...3f03b85fd365b84b0a908d3ea5217abd1a08a275': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Not quite sure why this is happening. I took the `3f03b85` commit from the workflow logs but no luck when trying to reproduce this manually.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out. In my case I just simply needed to run `$ git diff --name-only origin/dev...3f03b85fd365b84b0a908d3ea5217abd1a08a275`.

Seems like I was just missing `origin/` in front of the branch name.